# Run a UIWebView through an external server (Different IP Address and Port)

Tags: ios, uiwebview, proxy

I'm trying to make an iOS application which is essentially acting like a proxy server. It has a `UIWebview` which displays content just like Safari would. However, what I want to do is have all data traffic coming from an external IP address and port such as those suggested here: http://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/

My current code is just the simple code of:

```
NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.google.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest: request];
```

Say I had the IP Address: 177.101.8.13 and the port: 8080 - How could I implement that into my code above so the request comes from that server, as opposed to the server/network I am currently on? I had a look at `ASIHTTPRequest` but couldn't see how I could implement that in this situation...

Thanks!

*(Sorry about my terminology regarding this)

Answer (score 0):

If you setup a proxy server in the device's settings, `NSURLConnection` automatically uses the proxy server. Otherwise, you have to rewrite the request.

All requests over proxy servers use HTTP 1.1. You use the IP address of the proxy server in the request, but in the Host header, you send the actual host that you are attempting to reach. Include the port in the Host header if it's other than 80.

Use [NSMutableURLRequests](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s `setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:` method to set specific headers.

Where `request` is the NSMutableURLRequest:

```
[request setValue:@"google.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! How exactly would you rewrite the request? I'm sorry I'm only new to this!